# How to check logrotate syntax?

Tags: logrotate

We are suspecting a typo in the /etc/logrotate.d/FOO file.

How can we check it? So far I can see from:

https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate

maybe this?:

```
logrotate -df /etc/logrotate.d/FOO 2>&1 | grep -i error
```

Comment: Have you tried that command (without the `grep` filter)? What did it show you?

Comment: no, the question is not about specific typo. The question is for how to generally check for any typo/syntax issues. Thanks!

Comment: Running `logrotate` manually and inspecting the output would be a generic answer. If you're having specific issues with a log rotation configuration, then please include this configuration in the question.

Comment: Quite. The only answer I can give at the moment is `logrotate -df /etc/logrotate.d/FOO 2>&1 | ${PAGER-less}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logrotate syntax can be verified before with the flag -v

```
logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.d/FOO
```

If the file for the rotation presents an error it should appear.

Comment: NOTE: This command also does the log rotation.

Comment: A better option may be `logrotate --debug /etc/logrotate.d/FOO`. Check the man page for details.

Answer (score 8):

I concur with Vlad's comment on the current answer. The safe way to **just check syntax without actually rotating anything** is to use the debug option.

From `man logrotate`:

```
       -d, --debug
              Turns  on  debug  mode  and implies -v.  In
              debug mode, no changes will be made to  the
              logs or to the logrotate state file.
```

Example on my machine:

```
$ logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd 
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/httpd

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/httpd/*_log  5242880 bytes (10 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/httpd/access_log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/httpd/error_log
  log does not need rotating
not running postrotate script, since no logs were rotated
```

Adding the `-f` option will force the rotation to be *actually performed* (whether it needs it or not), allowing further analysis.

Summary:

```
-d    Just debug, don't actually rotate.
-df   Actually perform rotation and debug (includes verify).
-vf   Actually perform rotation and just verify.
```

Comment: This is the best answer.